# Confused with encode and decode

Tags: python

So I want to print a Hebrew ( or any other language ) by writing the hexadecimal values of the letter, decode it and print it to the terminal.

This is what I tried, I got the code page of cp862 from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_862 and trying to print the first letter. It outputs something else and not the wanted result.

What did I do wrong ?

```
letter = b'\x05\xD0'
print(letter.decode('cp862'))
```

OUTPUT :

wahalez@wahalez:~/dev/python$ python p25.py

╨

When do I use encode and when do I use decode ?

**EDIT :**

Another bizzare behavior is I swapped the bytes and decoded it to utf-16 and it worked. Why ? ..

```
letter2 = b'\xD0\x05'
print(letter2.decode('utf-16'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misread that chart.  The value `0x05D0` is the *unicode* code point for that character.  The value `0x80` is the CP862 value (see the `8_` on the right, and the `_0` at the top?).  So if you were to write:

```
>>> letter = b'\x80'
>>> print(letter.decode('cp862'))
א
```

You would get what you want.

---

> how can I use the unicode instead ? and with what encoding ?

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do. If you just want to use a character from the table, you can just copy and paste it.  E.g:

```
letter = 'א`
```

There's no need to muck about with encoding or decoding.

If you want to produce a character from a specific unicode codepoint, just use the `chr` function:

```
>>> print(chr(0x05d0))
א
```

Comment: what the _ are for ?

Comment: For filling in with the number from the other axis.  `8_` + `_0` == `80`.

Comment: how can I use the unicode instead ? and with what encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy abbreviation; BADTIE: Bytes Are Decoded, Text Is Encoded.

Also, you're confusing the Unicode code point with the `cp862` value.

The hebrew letter Aleph is Unicode codepoint 0x05D0, but in codepage 862 it's 0x80.

Try this:

```
In [3]: b = b'\x80'
Out[3]: b'\x80'

In [4]: b.decode('cp862')
Out[4]: 'א'
```

To use the unicode code point, try:

```
In [12]: chr(0x05D0)
Out[12]: 'א'
```

Comment: Ok so I used the right method. Now why this doesn't work ? :(

Answer (score 0):

- In python strings, bytes and byte sequences are called flat sequences, meaning that they are indexed but they are not the same type as containerized sequences such as lists or tuples,
- any string character has a fixed identity called *code point*. *Code points* are decimals between 0 and 0 to 1,114,111.
- the built-in function `ord()` taken a single character and returns an integer that represents the code point of a character

`print([chr(i) for i in range(100,120)])`

```
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']
```

`ord('€')`

```
8364
```

code point have the form U+prefix

for letter A the code point is U+0041 and for the Euro sign is U+20AC

if we wrap `ord()` with `hex()` we get he hexadecimal representation of the character

`hex(ord('A'))`

```
'0x41'
```

`hex(ord('€'))`

```
'0x20ac'
```

Now if you think about this form the viewpoint of a machine, think that all of this is written in a machine language. So you `decode()` the machine language to get it to the format that is legible to you, the user.

`b'\x41'.decode('UTF_8')`

```
'A'
```

`b'\x41\x00'.decode('UTF_16')`

```
'A'
```

b'\x41' and b'\x41\x00' are byte sequences for the letter A in utf-8 and utf-16 encoding

`b'\xe2\x82\xac'.decode('UTF_8')`

```
'€'
```

`b'\xac\x20'.decode('UTF_16')`

```
'€'
```

and when you encode you are converting a byte sequence back into the language that the machine understands.

byte sequences are machine recognized representations of code points
we

.encode() strings to bytes and .decode() bytes to strings

the mapping between a string character and a byte is interpreted using UTF-8 (or UTF-16, gb2312...) encoding

`"café".encode('utf_8')`

```
b'caf\xc3\xa9'
```

`"café".encode('utf_16')`

```
b'\xff\xfec\x00a\x00f\x00\xe9\x00'
```

`'El Niño'.encode('utf_8')`

```
b'El Ni\xc3\xb1o'
```

So use `.encode()` when the instance object is in hebrew or is characters, use `.decode()` when your instance is a byte sequence such as the byte sequence `b'\x41\x00'` for the letter A.

In a very similar behavior the class method `bytes()` takes in characters and encodes them just like `.encode()` into byte sequences.

`bytes("El Niño", encoding = 'utf_16')`

```
b'\xff\xfeE\x00l\x00 \x00N\x00i\x00\xf1\x00o\x00'
```

all the code above is in python3.8. Things are different in python 2 in regards to datatypes. So just be cautious if you're trying this in python 2